Selenium Test failing in CI/CD pipeline
I've developed test scripts using Selenium to test a browser application. The scripts works fine in my local machine but when test runs in the pipeline, it fails.
The part where it is failing is when asserting is equals the text that is displayed.
The info box contains these additional character and line breakers.
siteInfoTxt = "\r\nThis will be the address"

So I've removed them using the following code:
String InfoMessageString = siteInfoTxt.Substring(1);

String InfoSubString =InfoMessageString.Replace("\r\n", "");

and then used an assert to verify the text:
Assert.IsTrue(InfoSubString.Equals("This will be the address"));

This works perfectly in my local machine but fails in the pipeline.
I've also tried just:
String InfoSubString = InfoMessageString.Replace("\r\n", "");

Same behavior; local works, pipeline doesn't.
My local machine is Windows and the Agent host that I'm running is Linux in Azure DevOps.

Remember that on Windows, a newline is \r\n. On Linux, it's just \n. Could that be impacting your test cases? Assuming your tests are written in C#, you can use Environment.NewLine to get the correct, platform-specific newline sequence. Depending on where your application's \r\n is coming from, that could be the culprit.

This was exactly the reason. Thanks Daniel!

Hi @captainjack, Thx for your time to share the update. Would you consider Daniel's answer below as the resolution to your query in this post. Thx.

Since this comment was actually the correct answer, here it is for posterity:
Remember that on Windows, a newline is \r\n. On Linux, it's just \n. Could that be impacting your test cases? Assuming your tests are written in C#, you can use Environment.NewLine to get the correct, platform-specific newline sequence. Depending on where your application's \r\n is coming from, that could be the culprit.

mostly pipelines run on linux if so try to run on headless mode

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
